# What is the best approach to launch a lambda with POST parameters when a file is put into a s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Assume I have a lambda function with the following `main.py` :

```py
def lambda_handler(event, context):
   customer = event["customer"]
   response = handler(customer=customer)
   return response
```

I have a bucket `customers` that can contains files with a prefix describing some customers `customer=customer1`,  `customer=customer2`, etc.

I would like to run the lambda when a `.json` file is put on a bucket s3 `customers` with one of the prefix above. And I would like to run the lambda depending on the prefix with an event `customer` that is set using the prefixes. But, I think that's not possible to use directly the s3 trigger for this.

Do you know best practices to do this ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: One option(not tried) would be to make a rule in eventbridge for  s3 putobject in the specific bucket, put a json and see what event do you get. The based on that you can customise your rule and trigger the lambda.

Comment: I will try and let you know asap